# When copying folders and entire subtrees what is the difference between cp and rsync

Tags: rsync, cp

Upon my initial looking both cp and rsync will copy an entire directory structure.

That being said, what is the purpose for each and which is better?

```
cp -R $source $destination
```

vs

```
rsync -auq $source $destination
```

I was trying to look into and figure this out more, but they both seemed to copy an entire directory around the same speed.

Does one leverage another?  When cloning someone's HD which is the best course of action and why?

Comment: Well one difference is that rsync is like a merge tool, can be restarted, works over ssh with auth. If you are dealing with something locally that will succeed and won't ever need to keep the newer file etc, the difference is small.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main purpose of rsync not to copy directory from to the same system or machine It efficiently copies and sync files to or from a remote system.
Remote system like two different machines

and if you need the difference if you use them locally  see [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/43014/copying-a-large-directory-tree-locally-cp-or-rsync)

Comment: my client is having my copy stuff from 1 computer to another.  The issue is that they keep a machine blackboxed from the network... So they want me to write a script which would copy the source system to a USB and then from USB to the target machine.  Still, was not sure which would be better.  Since rsync makes sense to use in my case, im having issues trying to understand why i would or would not want to use `cp` instead.

Comment: see the link if you want to know more feature  of rsync 
in your situation I would use rsync as it means that if it is interrupted for any reason, then you can restart it easily with very little cost. And being rsync, it can even restart part way through a large file. The simplest way to preserve most things is to use the -a flag – ‘archive.’

Comment: It seems the big differences then are restarting part way through files, simplicity of file exclusion etc.  Seems like it may be the best course then.  When doing cp, i guess the files are smaller and you arent necessarily moving an entire system.